# Crystal Reports assumes wrong datatype of column from stored proc

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

What can be the reason that Crystal Reports Engine sometimes thinks that a field, that is returned from some stored procedure, that is in fact is of type `money`, is a `varchar 255`? Because of that I cannot apply any number formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you have the field cast as money?  Did you change the datatype recently, and not select Verify Database in Crystal Reports afterwards?  If so, it could just be Crystal Reports being difficult; I've seen it do strange things from time to time with no real expalantion why.

That said, you could always create a Formula Field that contains:

```
ToNumber({YourTable.YourField})
```

You can then show this formula field on your report, and apply number formatting to the field.  I know it's not the best answer, but it's a viable workaround.

Comment: Yup, I forgot to cast the result field :) The field that I expected to be money data type was in fact nvarchar(500). Thanks )))

Comment: >Did you change the datatype recently, and not select Verify Database in Crystal Reports afterwards?

Exactly what I forgot to do! Doh!