# Crystal Reports: why is memo-type field truncated at 255 characters?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm working in Crystal Reports XI (11.5.12.1838) running on a remote Windows system and accessed via Citrix. The data is coming from a Blackbaud Raiser's Edge export.

I have two different custom reports which need to display a Note (from Raiser's Edge) that can be of any length. In both cases, the database line was just dragged and dropped into a field in the report. It's set to grow with no maximum. In one report, it works; in the other, it does not, but truncates the text at 255 characters (or perhaps bytes: the RTF version was cut off earlier in the text).

The criteria for the reports are different (one is reporting on a single constituent, the other [which doesn't work] on constituents connected to a specific individual). However, I don't know well enough what might cause this problem to narrow down what aspects of the report configuration need adjustment.

Any ideas? I'll note that in the broken report the field grows correctly and is type 'memo' -- it just grows enough to hold 255 characters and then stops.

Edit: no, formula fields aren't involved. I can't really split the string in the database.

Edit 2: Thank you all for your suggestions. Database is up-to-date and field shows as Memo in Crystal Reports. Joins are the same in both reports (the one that works and the one that doesn't) and the memo field isn't involved in linking. CR annoyingly won't let you browse data on a memo field, but the Length() function is returning 255 for the field. Unless you all can think of a reason for CR to truncate the data, I may have a bug in Raiser's Edge causing this problem.

Edit 3: I pulled up the MDB in a hex editor and the full text (past 255 characters) is there, so I'm doing something wrong in Crystal Reports and can't blame Blackbaud for this one.

**Edit 4: Finally fixed!** Okay, I don't understand *why* this was the problem, but I discovered purely by accident that selecting and unselecting "Select Distinct Records" causes this problem. If it's on, the memo gets truncated. If it's off, it doesn't. Can any of you explain to this poor fool why that happens?

Comment: are you accessing memo field in Grouping Formulas or Selection Formulas or any other Formula Fields?

Comment: i think there is no solution for this. Can you split your string into 2 parts in the database and then display as 1 in CR?

Comment: Have you done a "Verify Database" to refresh the fields? Or does CR already list the field type as memo? Can you verify the data from the export actually contains more than 255 chars. Also, the memo field's bottom edge should be at the bottom of a section so it can grow and not overwrite other fields...

Comment: I think the key here is that it works in one report (with one table) and fails in another report (with two tables).  Are you letting Crystal determine how to join the tables?  I've found that it is usually best to click "Clear links" in the Links tab of the database expert, and then manually connect them.  (I'm guessing that the memo field is being used in the join.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports assumes wrong datatype of column from stored proc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701192/crystal-reports-assumes-wrong-datatype-of-column-from-stored-proc)

Answer (score 3):

I have just resolved the same problem and discovered that a text formula value in the report was being truncated at 255 characters, due to an unmapped data field, revealed by the *verify database* option.

Once I had dealt with the unmapped data field, the truncated field immediately expanded its output beyond 255 characters.